# Schedule a job with replicated containers on different hosts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I am trying to run a Kubernetes job that will deploy the same pod on each host and run the same command in each of the pods (identical execution). There are 5 workers in the cluster `worker01`, `worker02`, ..., `worker05`. This definition schedules one pod on a random host:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hdd-integrity
  labels:
    job: hdd-integrity
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hdd-integrity
          image: some-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["python", "check.py"]
          args:
            - "--threads=88"
            - "--md5=2a3f98b6eb50326cf69257c5c5fc7e35"
            - "--dir=/mnt"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: store
              mountPath: /mnt
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: store
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: subgrp1-subvol1-pvc
            readOnly: false
  backoffLimit: 1
```

All pods should mount to the same pvc. Not sure what is the best way to achieve this. Daemonsets will not work because they do not provide `restartPolicy: Never`

Answer (score 1):

A Job will be scheduled to a random node and that's by design. To run a workload in each node use [daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

> A DaemonSet ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As
> nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are
> removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a
> DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule a pod per node for a specific application, the right way to do so in the Kubernetes is using the [Daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

> A DaemonSet ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As
> nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are
> removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a
> DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.

Further, if you want to schedule each pod in a different node, you can look at [pod anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) concepts.

Answer (score 0):

DaemonSets do not have `restartPolicy: Never` however this job needs to only run once. So a simple solution will be to use jinja2 templates:

```
{%- set workers = ["worker01", "worker02", "worker03", "worker04", "worker05"]
%}
{%- for w in workers %}
{%- set worker = w %}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hdd-integrity-job-{{ worker }}
  labels:
    job: hdd-integrity
    tag: "0.0.6"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hdd-integrity
          image: my-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
          args:
            - "time python check.py --threads=3"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cephfs-store
              mountPath: /mnt
      nodeSelector:
        node: {{ worker }}
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: cephfs-store
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: subgrp1-subvol1-pvc
            readOnly: false
  backoffLimit: 0
{%- endfor %}
```

```sh
pip install jinja2  
alias render_template='python -c "from jinja2 import Template; import sys; print(Template(sys.stdin.read()).render());"' 
cat hdd-integrity.yaml.j2 | render_template | kubectl apply -f -
```